# Statistical tests of the form "is my PDF correct?"

Tags: statistics

Let's say we observe some data points $x_i$ and we hypothesize
they come from some continuous r.v. X which has PDF $f$.

I know that e.g. the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test can be applied to this kind of problems.

Do these tests/problems of the form *"is my PDF correct?"* have a specific name?

These problems can be viewed as continuous analogues of problems of the kind "is my PMF correct?" Example of the latter is the test if a given e.g. 6-sided die is fair. In that test our $H_0$ hypothesis is that $P(X=i) = 1/6$ which is a PMF and we ask: "Is my PMF correct?".  Do these also have some name?

This question came to me while watching this last lecture of this MIT course.

https://youtu.be/rYefUsYuEp0?t=2167

Comment: goodness of fit test

Comment: Specification testing?

Comment: These are goodness-of-fit tests, including also the Anderson-Darling test and the $\chi^2$ goodness of fit test.

Comment: OK... so in both cases PDF/PMF it's still a "goodness of fit test", is that what it is being said here?